# Does having 4 installed OS affect my RAM usage?

Tags: system-installation

I installed 4 Os's(*Ubuntu 13.04,Ubuntu 13.10,Windows 8,Windows 8.1* in logical partition) on my HDD.

Does this configuration may affect my RAM in some other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the RAM is all given to the active operating system unless you are running another operating system simultaneously by creating a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, your 4 os are on your HDD, so you will choose one on the boot menu, so the others won't be solicited by anyway on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is temporary memory which is cleared when your computer is totally off. If you boot into one OS, the OS will only use the RAM and not other OS-es since you are not booting into it and it is not running.